# Why the electric field inside a capacitor isn't nul?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, conductors

I have a doubt regarding this point, i know that the electric field inside a conductor is null, and the capacitor is made by two conducting plates, so what s the point here?

Comment: A capacitor is made by two conducting plates _that do not touch each other_.  The electric field is in the space between the plates.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field is zero inside a space that is completely enclosed by a conductor. In a capacitor you have two plates that are electrically isolated. This allows for an electric field to be set up between the plates, and this in turn allows for the capacitor to store a certain amount of charge / energy, which is desirable for many electrical circuits.

If you start with two parallel plates (a capacitor) but then connect the ends together to make a fully enclosed space, the act of connecting the plates will cause a short circuit that turns the capacitor into a conductive box instead.